# Cassandra CQL implementation

Tags: cql

```
INSERT INTO patient(patient_id, pt_name, pt_dob, pt_gender, pt_occupation, pt_address, pt_city_town_vill, pt_district, pt_state, pt_pin, pt_country, pt_email_id, pt_phone, ecp_name, ecp_relation, ecp_address, ecp_city_town_vill, ecp_district, ecp_state, ecp_pin, ecp_country, ecp_email_id, ecp_phone, history, blood_grp, allergy) VALUES (c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34, 'Rahul', {'2015-12-3 23:21'}, 'male', 'farmer', 'nadia', 'berhampore','murshidabad','west bengal', '700300', 'india', 'abc@hi.com', '990876541', 'Rohan', 'family-friend', 'abc', 'downtown', 'dinajpur', 'bengal', '788905', 'zgyuj', 'dd@gc.com', '990742568', {'2015-12-3 10:00' : 'has diabetes and high blood pressure'}, 'O positive', {'rashes appear on consumption of prawns' : 'is allergic to quinone medicine'});
```

someone please solve this error...

```
<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message=line 1:367 mismatched character ',' expecting set null">
```

Comment: Can you giv us the DDL for table patient and your cassandra CQL version ?

Answer (score 0):

Check character 367 (per error message). Is `patient_id` a uuid? I don't think `c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34` is valid